# Instancing a java.io.File to read a resource from classpath

Tags: java

Supposing that I've a project structure as follows:

```
+ src
---+ main
------+ java
------+ resources
```

How can I define a `java.io.File` instance that is able to read an xml from *resources* folder?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your program's working directory is.

You can get your working directory at runtime via `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

[Here's a link with more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Once you've got that, create a relative filepath pointing to your resource folder.

For example, if your working directory is src, create a relative filepath like so:

```
new File(Paths.get("main","resources").toString());
```

There are weaknesses with this approach as the actual filepath you use may change when you deploy your application, but it should get you through some simple development.

Comment: By setting Paths.get("src","main","resources").toString() +  "myfile.xml", it works only as local application (fails on server 'cause the path is related to my development environment).

Comment: Can you solve this by ensuring the same directory structure is followed on your server and your development environment?

Comment: No, this isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

No, use an InputStream, with the path starting under resources.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStrem("/.../...");
```

Or an URL

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/.../...");
```

This way, if the application is packed in a jar (case sensitive names!) it works too. The URL in that case is:

```
"jar:file://... .jar!/.../..."
```

If you need the resource as file, for instance to write to, you will need to copy the resource as initial template to some directory outside the application, like `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

```
Path temp = Files.createTempFile("pref", "suffix.dat");
Files.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream(...), temp, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
File file = temp.toFile();
```

As @mjaggard commented, `createTempFile` creates an empty file,
so `Files.copy` will normally fail unless with option REPLACE_EXISTING.

Comment: I cannot use InputStream, 'cause I've to call an external constructor that has as argument a java.io.File

Comment: As you seem to be using maven one would either produce the file as a second build product, or in code use `File.createTempFile` to make a copy. _If_ one wanted to be strict. Have added the code.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work because `createTempFile` creates and empty file and `copy` requires that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @mjaggard thanks, createTempFile was an afterthought, and I did not take care of the consequences. Corrected.