# Trying to open Openoffice file using a link in java Toolkit

Tags: java, unix

I tried  to open from the normal eclipse it worked fine, but when exported same file to a jar
its giving an error.
Can anyone help?

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Process process;
            try {
                String resourceLocation = MainPanel.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
                resourceLocation += "/com/microsoftplatformready/resources/images/endUserLicenseAgreement.docx";
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("soffice -reader "+resourceLocation);
                process.waitFor();
                process.destroy();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error you got?

Comment: I could not able to open the file which is in jar file   "Error:General input output error while accessing"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654597/instancing-a-java-io-file-to-read-a-resource-from-classpath/24654846#24654846 - My solution : first create a tempfile with the resource inside the jar, and then give it to OpenOffice.

Comment: I am relatively new to Java, can you explain briefly the procedure to create tempfile in resource directory, and how to use it in my case

Answer (score 0):

As Joop Eggen already said in the comment, first create a new temp file and copy your actual document to the temp file and open this one instead.

The reason is simply, Openoffice can't read files stored in an archive.

```
Path temp = Files.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix.ext");
Files.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceLocation), temp);
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("soffice -reader "+ temp.toAbsolutePath().toString())
```